# Find Wordpress/#7 CSS File

Tags: css, wordpress

EDIT: No URL but this is what I mean:

[image]

I'm trying to change the colour of my header font and the size of my font in my footer on my Avada theme.

Now when I use Firebug to see which CSS file those respective items are located in, it tells me Wordpress/#7(or whatever), and I don't know where to find those.  I've already looked through my theme options and I can't find them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send us a URL? Perhaps we can help you find it there.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a local installation, so I can't even do that.  Thanks though!

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. That's interesting. Perhaps this is loaded in the theme settings from the backend?

Comment: Use Firefox Developer Tools-> Inspector, select the header , it will show you the corresponding CSS.

Comment: I tried that, and it's coming back with inline:984.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firebug, when you view the class in the CSS visibility sidepanel, you should be able to see a referenced style sheet where that class is located.

[Here is an example of where its located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHZ4o.jpg)

Comment: I've tried that, and it tells me that it's in the /wordpress/ folder.  So I don't know where to go.